# Create NuGet package of Function App project

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to create a NuGet package of a .NET Core 2.1 Azure Functions project. The problem is that `dotnet pack` just creates a folder structure like presented below, but not the `.nupkg` file itself. What may be wrong?

**Publish directory tree:**

-- bin

-- Function

---- function.json

-- FunctionApp.deps.json

-- host.json

**FunctionApp.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: If you use VS. Go to properties of project and then tap package. Add a check mark on : Generate NuGet package on build. And rebuild your solution

Answer (score 0):

.nupkg is the manifest that described your NuGet package. To generate the .nupkg file you have to add required properties in the .csproj project file.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>AppLogger</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>name</Authors>
    <Company>company</Company>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

You can generate the Nuget package using the following command.

```
dotnet pack tempproject.csproj -o D:\Temp --no-build /p:Configuration=debug /p:PackageVersion=1.0.12.0 --verbosity Detailed
```